# Python TkinterのGUIを作成するとき、アイコン画像の設定を２回行うと正しくアイコンファイルが読み込めなくなる

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinterライブラリのGUI作成手順において、ウィンドウのアイコンを設定するとき、
アイコンの指定を２回記述すると画像読み込みエラーになるのは何がいけないのでしょうか。
普通２回指定するなという話なのはそうなのですが、ビルドは通ったうえで取り込み失敗になります。
エラーコードが出ないので何が理由なのかいまいちつかめていないです。

※icon.icoは相対パスでディレクトリ直下に存在し、アナコンダプロンプトで実行する際はcd設定でディレクトリ直下を参照しています。

```
#正常な例
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('ウィンドウ名')        
root.geometry('300x200')
root.iconbitmap(default='icon.ico')
root.mainloop()

#だめな例
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('ウィンドウ名')        
root.geometry('300x200')
root.iconbitmap(default='icon.ico')
root.iconbitmap(default='icon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2022/10/24追記
ご提案いただいた内容のなかで正常に実行できたパターンのソースコードを追記します。

```
#成功例１
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('ウィンドウ名')        
root.geometry('300x200')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
root.mainloop()

#成功例２
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('ウィンドウ名')        
root.geometry('300x200')
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: #だめな例 をwindows11で試したところ「画像読み込みエラー」は発生しませんでした。質問者さんの環境は何でしょうか？

Comment: win10 python3.8 でアナコンダプロンプトからビルドしてます。こちらはエラーの際に代替アイコンが表示される状態になります。エラーを画像で掲載させていただきました。

Comment: すみません。再確認したところ当方でも読み込めていませんでした。

Comment: 再現性があってなによりです。これが原因なのかわからないのですが、複数のGUIを作成するとすべてのウィンドウのアイコンがまとめてエラーアイコンになってしまって困りました。ウィンドウに親子関係があるときは別に親のアイコンを勝手に継承してるような感じがするので構わないのですが、１つのシステムの中で別々のモジュールとしてアイコンを切り替えようとすると本件のような挙動を示したので可能な限り単純化した結果としてこのような事態を引き起こしており困りました。

Comment: 余談ですが `default` は Windows 環境でのみ有効な機能のようです。 https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.html#M31 クロスプラットフォームを目指すならば、この機能に依存しない方がよさそうです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。win依存なんですね、勉強になりました。現状クロス開発予定はないのでwindows上で動けばヨシなのですが、今時点で動かなかったので参考になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

調べてみた所、Tkinterでも複数のアイコン設定方法が存在するようです。
もしかしたら以下のリンクの方法で改善するかもしれません。
・[www.delftstack.com](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-set-window-icon-in-tkinter/)
・[Stackoverflow.com(英語)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929479/embed-icon-in-python-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: 私も1番目の記事は見ました。私のところでは「TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file」エラーが出てしまいダメでしたね。。。（pngでもjpgでも）

Comment: 前者URLリンク先の記述によって改善がありました。
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
または
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
で取り込むと２重定義した場合であっても正常にアイコン画像を表示できました。
ただし、両者とも.icoファイル系ではなく画像拡張子系しか受け取らないようなので、ファイルをicoからpng等へ変える必要がありました。

Comment: >merino様　自分はicoファイルパスを送ったら仰るようなエラーが出ましたがpng画像でカレントディレクトリ指定をしていれば正常に確認ができました。参照パスがずれている可能性はありませんか？